# How to start Visual Studio with TFS credentials

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, command-line, tfs

Me and my team mates share the same five-six TFS credentials (long story).

For work with TFS we connect in VPN to an external domain and we use this command to start VS:

C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:EXTERNALDOMAIN\my_user_name /netonly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

This way is a little nightmare: runAs doen't allows to register the password in the command itself, and we are 20+ persons sharing the same credentials, sometimes we lock ourself, 'cause someone change the password and someones don't it know...

So I created this little program, where the password is stored in a common file on our net.
This solution work successfully in local, but not with the external domain.

Someone can explain why and how can I fix it?

```
class Program
{
    static string vsPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe";
    static string userAndDomain = "";
    static string Password = "";


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Read credentials from file:
        string processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        string dir = appPath + "\\" + processName + ".txt";

        if (File.Exists(dir))
        {
            var files = File.ReadAllLines(dir).ToList();
            userAndDomain = files[0];
            Password = files[1];
        }

        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = GetProcessStartInfo();
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    public static ProcessStartInfo GetProcessStartInfo()
    {
        var pswString = new SecureString();
        Password.ToList().ForEach(c => pswString.AppendChar(c));

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = vsPath,
            UserName = userAndDomain,
            Password = pswString,
            Verb = "runas",
            UseShellExecute = false
        };

        return startInfo;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try this code to connect to TFS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958(v=vs.120).aspx.

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT this doesn't works for me..